# Adding a Pause/Play button on selenium webdriver tests C#

Tags: c#, winforms, selenium-webdriver

I have been asked to add a play/pause button to my selenium test project so that the user can press "**play**" to do the next step manually.

I haven't coded in project for months so i am confused, is there a way to do what they asked me?

I am using windows form for the project.

EDIT: Im not trying to interrupt a video but the steps of the test, for example the test navigate to a page then the user press "play" to do the next step until another command...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to play & pause video using Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10043730/how-to-play-pause-video-using-selenium)

Comment: No in that question they asked how to interrupt a video, i want to interrupt the test

Comment: https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/23095/can-we-do-a-play-and-pause-kind-of-thing-in-web-automation-with-or-without-selen