# I want to check if online video is streaming or not. How to do it in Python?

Tags: python

I want to write a script to check if I am able to stream an online video in a website. I just want a binary no (0 or 1) to see if the content is working or not and I want to do it via Python.

I have search in the internet but couldn't found an adequate answer.

Comment: Can you mention the website name? Although a simple way might be take 4-5 screenshot and compare the difference. If it's black/gray/loading state the difference will be different than if it were playing. There might be simpler approach if you mention the website/ JS library used

Comment: Websites like Netflix.

Comment: What do you mean by "if online video is streaming or not"?

Comment: I am at work and netflix is blocked :/ one approach might be to find a element on the webpage( the pause overlay) or the pause/play button check it's state and determine the video state.

Comment: Well, one can use the tools like **Selenium WebDriver** or **appium** to test the video streaming. Its's like passing through many odds to test the video streaming on a platform.

Comment: Have a quick look at such approach mentioned here; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10043730/how-to-play-pause-video-using-selenium?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easier solution would be to calculate your internet consumption. If your internet consumption is higher than a certain limit, then you may assume that your streaming is working fine. If not, you may configure an alert.

Comment: Thankyou @jainil. This might be a way for me to move forward.